# Save and retrieve text to html

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I am creating a CMS application. I am trying to save the text in the DB(MySQL). While trying to retrieve the value, I see that the line breaks are not reflecting in my HTML.

How can i retrieve the text with the respective formatting.

I have already tried using `htmlentities()`, `nl2br()` in php, but that doesn't work.

Eg:
Input text:

Hello World.

This is John

value that I see after being retrieved from DB: 
Hello World. This is John.

Comment: You should add example code for saving it to database and retrieve from database as well as print to HTML. 
Only output will not help.

Comment: use textarea HTML tag to save and retrieve it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You are storing data without any HTML tag, if you want to display the data as it was when you typed it in the text input, i think you use a WYSIWYG editor which wraps your text into HTML tags, there are many of them like ckeditor, summernote.